# Perforce replica server that can write to main server and has build capability

Tags: replication, perforce, proxy-server

I need to customize the Perforce server to achieve the following requirements:

1. I need a local replica server which gets synced with the main server in a different geographical location. I can have the same time zone settings for the local and main servers
2. The client should be able to commit to the replica server.
3. The replica server will have build capability as well as a test frame work that is run whenever a build is succesfull.
4. Once the build and test is succesfull the code should get committed to main server.

I know that the replica server provided by perforce is used as a readonly server which can't write to main server and the forwarding replica just forwards the commands to main server.

I can't use proxy server, as the local server should work even when the main server is offline.

Is it possible to do this? Can anyone point me to some articles which would help me to set up such a server

I had asked the same question in the Perforce forum, but the question is still under verification by moderators.

Comment: What is the benefit of requirement 2? Are these commits intended to be permanent? Or will they be discarded after some time?

Comment: @BryanPendleton After committing to the replica, if the build is succesfull then the commit will be made to the main server, else it should be discarded. the bandwidth to the main server is limited. We don''t want all the client to update and commit to the main server. We want the commit to happen only when it's necessary(when build in replica is green).

Comment: @BryanPendleton I received a reply from Perforce Forum. They suggested to look into P4Sandbox. I am try it out now.

Answer (score 0):

An edge/commit setup may meet your requirements, as an Edge Server handles some local operations associated with workspaces and work in progress.

As well as read-only commands, the following operations can be performed on an Edge Server:

syncing, checking out, merging, resolving, and reverting files

More information about edge/commit archetecture is available here:

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4dist/chapter.distributed.html

You may also want to look at BuildFarm servers:

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4dist/chapter.replication.html#DB5-72814

Hope this helps,
Jen!

Answer (score 0):

Build Server doesn't allow build work spaces to submit files. If submitting files is required as part of the build process, consider the use of an edge server to support your automated build processes.

With the implementation of edge servers in 2013.2, we now recommend that you use an edge server instead of a build farm server.

Edge servers offer all the functionality of build farm servers and yet offload more work from the main server and improve performance, with the additional flexibility of being able to run write commands as part of the build process.